# Fastest way to find element with same attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, attributes, append

I am parsing some divs with a url as an ID, and in case the same url/ID exists, I want to bypass it. So on every append, I'm searching through 100's of divs to find the same value of an attribute that all those div's have.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div data-id="http://stackoverflow.com"></div>
<div data-id="http://engadget.com"></div>
<div data-id="http://9gag.com"></div>
<div data-id="http://reddit.com"></div>
<div data-id="http://facebook.com"></div>
<div data-id="http://stackoverflow.com"></div>
<div data-id="http://twitter.com"></div>
<div data-id="http://mashable.com"></div>
```

So if stackoverflow exists, bypass:

```
$('div[data-id="http://www.stackoverflow"]').length
```

What would be the fastest way to do with pure js?

**EDIT:**

So after giving a try its more complicated that I thought:

Since I have to append first the content and then find if a data-id with certain value attribute exists twice, I'm struggling through the process to achive the fastest way possible.

Here's my **HTML**:

```
<div class="ele" data-id="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://engadget.com">http://engadget.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://9gag.com">http://9gag.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://reddit.com">http://reddit.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://facebook.com">http://facebook.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://twitter.com">http://twitter.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://mashable.com">http://mashable.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://bbc.com">http://bbc.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://twitter.ca">http://twitter.ca</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://google.com">http://google.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://apple.com">http://apple.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://cnn.com">http://cnn.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://imgur.com">http://imgur.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://9gag.com">http://9gag.com</div>
```

and here's my **js**:

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("ele")
for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    var b = a[i].getAttribute("data-id");
    if (document.querySelectorAll('div[data-id="' + b +'"]').length > 1){
        console.log(a[i])
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
<div class="ele" data-id="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://9gag.com">http://9gag.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://stackoverflow.com">http://stackoverflow.com</div>
<div class="ele" data-id="http://9gag.com">http://9gag.com</div>
```

of which both 9gag.com and stackoverflow.com exists more than twice.

**How do I leave only 1 of each and remove the rest?** & is this the fastest way possible of achieving this?

Comment: The way to answer your question is to test the performance for yourself. StackOverflow really can't accurately answer this question for you. You need to take the actual page(s) where you're performing the operation, and do some performance tests in the browsers that you care about. There's no guarantee that a single test will accurately represent all situations.

Comment: Is the final order important?

Comment: @Flimzy absolutely I'm afraid so

Comment: Wait... are you just trying to remove duplicates? If so, just do the DOM selection once, loop the elements, and put the `data-id` value in an object key. At every element check to see if the key already exists in the object, and if so, remove the element. That way you're doing only one DOM selection.

Comment: @CrazyTrain I absolutely agree I'm not looking for a performance test but rather an answer on something I'm can't figure out. If you read through my latest edit, I'm trying to find out how I could remove the multiple data attributes with same value but one.

Comment: @CrazyTrain What you have just said, Its what I'm trying to figure out how to do, thats why im on stackoverflow. I've tried so many non-generous ways and very unprofessional.

Comment: I'll post an answer in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var store = {};

var a = document.getElementsByClassName("ele");

for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < len; i++) {
    var id = a[i].getAttribute("data-id");
    if (store.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        a[i].parentNode.removeChild(a[i]);
        i--;
        len--;
    } else
        store[id] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Although this works, I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getAttribute' of undefined" error on loop.

Comment: @jQuerybeast: Oops, I ran into the "live list" problem. I'll update to iterate in reverse.

Comment: Thank you. Also I've mentioned that the last element stays alive. So instead of the first element stackoverflow, it gets deleted and the last one is alive. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @jQuerybeast: Ah, that's right. We do need a forward iteration. Ok, I'll update to decrement the counter when we do a remove.

Comment: You're welcome, and I just slipped in another quick update to decrement the `len` as well since I had it cached.

Answer (score 8):

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[data-id="http://www.stackoverflow"]').length;
```

---

```
var a = document.getElementsByClassName("ele")
for (i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    var b = a[i].getAttribute("data-id");
    var all = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-id="' + b +'"]');
    for (var j = 1; j < all.length; j++){//if there is more than 1 match remove the rest
        all[j].parentNode.removeChild(all[j]);
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ehMML/

Comment: Would that be the fastest way possible or is there any other method I should go with? Maybe I shouldn't be looping through 100's of attribute values?

Comment: @VivinPaliath so no Selector Api?

Comment: @jQuerybeast: This offloads that the lookup to the browser, which can do it a *lot* faster than you can. And unless you need to support *really* old browsers...

Comment: @Musa: I was preparing evidence for my `document.querySelectorAll` answer, but you got there before me.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Let's not be too hasty to make assumptions about performance. ;-) According to this update to @ Tamil's JSPerf, looping the divs is quicker in Firefox and Chrome. Of course these results can change with the next update.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Tamil's JSPerf doesn't do the loop either. What Tamil's JSPerf proves is that calling QSA directly is faster than asking jQuery to call QSA for you (which was surely obvious). :-) (jQuery will hand off any query to QSA it can, but first it has to check for jQuery-specific stuff, and that slows things down.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Well... Looks like I forgot to post the link to the update I made to that test! Here we go... http://jsperf.com/qsvsjqs/2

Comment: @Musa Can you please check my edit? Its more complicated than I thought.

Comment: @CrazyTrain Can you please check my edit? I'm actually looking for a difference way of achieving the same thing. Maybe there could be a faster way

Comment: Added `querySelector` to the perf :  http://jsperf.com/qsvsjqs/3 It is the fastest since it stops at the first occurrence whereas `querySelectorAll` must traverse all the divs.

Comment: @HBP: Sure, but that only tells you if there's at least one. OP needs to know if there's more than one.

Comment: @HBP: Wait... your test uses `querySelectorAll`, not `querySelector`

Comment: @Crazy Train: My bad on jsPerf, I've updated it. The OP wants to avoid adding duplicates so he need only test for his proposed addition and a Boolean existence tests suffices : add if test fails don't add if test succeeds.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: I've [updaed the jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/qsvsjqs/4) in a couple of ways: 1. Use 100 elements, since the OP's using them. 2. It wasn't actually finding any elements (the string it was searching for wasn't present). A valid test, but I think it's more useful to find an element. So I made it find the one at the very end (e.g., worst case). 3. Added a "loop until found" option that doesn't create an array, since all the OP needs is to find whether there's an entry. And it looks like Opera is doing something interesting with QSA/QS... But in any case, the map is the way to go.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Interesting. I knew that Opera had some serious optimizations in its `qSA`, but that's just nuts. It must be doing some sort of caching.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Must be, no question.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an associative array?

```
for ( ... ) {
    if ( defined foo[url] )
        next;
    foo[url] = 1;
    // Your logic here
}
```